# How do I use polyfills with babel in 2021?

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, polyfills, core-js

After reading https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-polyfill and https://alexbogovich.com/blog/core-js/, I'm still not sure what to do.

`@babel/polyfill` is deprecated. So should I just do `yarn add core-js regenerator-runtime` and import those into the entry file?

Comment: This is a really good question. The Babel docs have been confusing and contradictory about polyfills for years, compounded by the fact that they seem to deprecate and rename packages often. Are you using a JS framework? For example with Vue CLI it manages all this crap for us. As for the Node side of things, I just opted for using Typescript because again Babel is very hard to setup.

Comment: Totally agree! @user9993